# "uninitialized constant XmlSimple::Zlib" in ROR xml parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i am using gem 'xml-simple' to parse the xml data in Ruby on rails, but i am getting error called "uninitialized constant XmlSimple::Zlib". Can any body tell what the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [cobravsmongoose](http://cobravsmongoose.rubyforge.org/) will solve your problem :)

Comment: No the problem is solved by using one more gem called cobravsmongoose .. Thanks for your suggestion :)